# About extracting and converting emoji.ttf to .svg

Tags: python, svg, emoji, truetype, fontforge

I am using Windows 10 and I have installed Python 3.10.10 x64.

I copied NotoColorEmoji.ttf from Android phone's /system/fonts, which is an emoji font file, and I found a python script which can extract all emojis from it and convert them to 108x108px .PNGs, plus converting the .ttf to .ttx.

But is there any way to extract & convert it to .svg which is vector graphics? I googled and found that fontforge seems to be able to do that, but I am not sure about. I would like to have some of the emoji icons in vectors, which cannot be found anywhere.

If anyone knows how to get vector graphics from the .ttf, please teach me. Thanks in advance.

I haven't tried fontforge, and it seems not able to export colors from what I saw elsewhere.

Edit: I have tried fontforge and it said no bitmap strikes from the NotoColorEmoji.ttf. And the tool I used to extract PNGs is this one: https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools

Comment: I installed the font from the Debian repo and found it contains the description "Color emoji font using [CBDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cbdt) glyph data", which means it is a bitmap font. But when [downloading](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji?query=emoji) from Google directly, the version contains vector data in [COLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/colr) format. Fontforge unfortunately was not able to compose it correctly, but maybe your fonttool, which I don't know, has more luck.

Comment: @ccprog fonttool cannot convert them to .svg, only .png. If you want to try the .ttf I am using here you go. https://file.io/zGlcy5CK7P8F

Comment: As commented by @ccprog: **your samsung version** of the noto emoji font has stored all glyphs/emojis in CBDT bitmap format – so you need to find a COLR version using svg data e.g the one from google. If fonttools doesn't support svg extraction you could also install the free ["OpenType SVG Font Editor"](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/opentype-svg-font-editor/9NJ7K9JX60P1?hl=de-de&gl=de&rtc=1) from windows store.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.